# Eigenvalues of a high dimensional sample covariance matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, covariance, random-matrices

I am not a math/stat major, but I encountered high dimensional matrix in my research. Particularly, consider a sample covariance matrix of the form
$S_{X}=\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^{T}\mathbf{X}_{t}\mathbf{X}_{t}^{T},$ where $\mathbf{X}_{t}=\left( x_{1t},\ldots ,x_{Nt}\right) ^T.$
Assuming both $N$ and $T$ are large, then $S_{X}$ is a $N\times N$ high
dimensional sample covariance matrix. Since the elements in $\mathbf{X}_{t}$
could be correlated, $S_{X}$ may not be a diagonal matrix. My question is
what's the eigenvalues of $S_{X}$? Are there any references to find the
properties of the eigenvalues of $S_{X}?$ The results I need is that the
maximum eigenvalues of $S_{X}$ is bounded for large $N$ and $T.$ Thanks!

Comment: This is a good question. It really depends what you mean by "high dimensional." A lot of standard packages (LAPACK, MATLAB, etc.) can easily handle matrices with hundreds of rows, at a minimum, very quickly. The larger you get in terms of $N$ and $t$ the more helpful it may be to know more about the matrix.

Comment: Thanks for that. I am not asking for numerical computation, I am checking the properties of eigenvalues for large dimension matrix since $N$ is assumed large, and $S_X$ is a sample covariance matrix.

Answer (score 1):

With normal 0 mean assumptions, $TS_x$ is [Wishart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution) distributed and the joint distribution of eigenvalues is known in some case (see wiki). Some result about the dominant eigenvalue distribution was derived in

Khatri, C. G. "Non-central distributions of i th largest characteristic roots of three matrices concerning complex multivariate normal populations." [Annals of the Institute of Statistical Mathematics 21.1 (1969): 23-32.](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02532229)

Also this

Chiani, Marco. "Distribution of the largest eigenvalue for real Wishart and Gaussian random matrices and a simple approximation for the Tracy–Widom distribution." [Journal of Multivariate Analysis 129 (2014): 69-81.](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0047259X14000761?token=DDA755E57143ACA8CE440A190F9CAF30F53F8E97D8B0BF8F63D29D4AB6F81F1C07B72B4C27DFFFE61C6872830D9CAFCF).

You might start here.